# How to /tp only players in survival?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Let's say 3 people are in survival, and 2 people are in creative, What command can I use so it will only TP the people in survival ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the gamemode tag.

1.13+: `/teleport @a[gamemode=survival] x y z`
1.12-: `/teleport @a[m=0] x y z` (0 = survival, 1 = creative, 2 = adventure, 3 = spectator)

This'll teleport all players in survival mode to the location you specify; if you want to teleport the nearest player only, replace `@a` with `@p`.

**In bedrock, only the 1.12 style command works.**

Comment: Does this work for bedrock?

Comment: What's the point of providing 1.12 versions of commands when 1.13 was released years ago?

Comment: @pppery Because people might be playing on 1.12.2 (It's a very popular version)

Comment: @AMJ answer updated.

Comment: @pppery I play 1.8 and 1.15, so...